# Building an Android app feature that shares the current user's actions/screen

Tags: android, game-development

I am currently a college student working on my first android app. My group is working on a game as our project in which a lobby of four players take turns drawing an object based on the random word given by the app. The other players are to guess what the person is drawing. While most features have built on the frontend and backend, we are looking to wrap up the app and one of the few remaining features is being able to showcase the app's drawing activity on the other player's end in real-time or close to real-time. The only issue is that I don't know where to start looking to begin developing such a feature. Could someone point me in the right direction for such a feature or possibly give me a few suggestions?

Thank you kind internet strangers!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is front-end and back-end and Real-time communication technologies, such as Polling, Long Polling, WebSocket, SSE (Server-Sent Events).

Real-time applications, such as games, usually use WebSocket to achieve. WebSocket can define a listener and wait for you to send new data. When you receive new data, you can do the corresponding processing.